# Cos'è un "accomodatore di porci"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Il signor Podestà*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Possibile però che sua moglie Matilde se l’intendesse con Alfredo, l’**accomodatore di porci**? Il suo galoppino e debitore Maurizio giurava di sí. Ma che poteva ancora trovarci Alfredo in Matilde?

Non ho trovato l'espressione "accomodatore di porci" in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino faccia riferimento al mestiere di questo Alfredo, ma non riesco a capire di quale mestiere si tratti. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

**Aggiornamento:**

Matilde è la moglie del podestà. Maurizio è il galoppino e debitore del podestà.

Aggiungo un altro brano del racconto per dare un po' piú de contesto:

> Maurizio, d’altra parte, non aveva alcun interesse a mentirgli, a farlo imbestialire senza fondato motivo. Ad oggi gli doveva duecentocinquanta lire, un sacco di calciocianamide e una carrata di fieno. A detta di Maurizio, la prima volta era stata la notte in cui lui festeggiava a Niella il nuovo podestà di quel paese, ed era successo nella stalla. Matilde interrogata aveva risposto – senza affanno, per la verità – che quella notte Alfredo era in casa loro, nella stalla precisamente, ma perché chiamato da lei per paura che la vacca vecchia crepasse. Andava effettivamente soggetta ad attacchi ed ogni volta sembrava dover tirare i calci, e Alfredo di bestie in genere era competente almeno quanto il veterinario condotto, e le sue tariffe inferiori di un quarto.

Comment: Una ricerca su Google Books dà solo un paio di racconti di Fenoglio.

Comment: Secondo me significa semplicemente guardiano di maiali.

Comment: @abarisone Probabilmente con intento molto sarcastico.

Comment: Considerato che uno dei sensi di “accomodare” è “Disporre in modo adatto, preparare opportunamente: a. il campo per le semine. Ant., riferito a persona, collocarla, darle una sistemazione” (Treccani), e si dice anche di affari e simili, non potrebbe essere un affarista specializzato in maiali, che li compra e li vende?

Comment: @DaG: Quello che in questo [documento](https://www.montaione.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Gente-poca-parecchi-contadini-montaione.net_.pdf) viene chiamato "maialaio"? Ha senso.

Comment: Contesto please, Matilde è la moglie del Podestà?  Maurizio è il galoppino e il debitore del Podestà o di Alfredo, l'_accomodatore di porci_?

Comment: Il contesto borghese del racconto mi fa credere che Alfredo, diversamente da Pelle d'Asino, non sia un guardiano di maiali.

Comment: @PoldoSbaffini: Ho cercato di aggiungere un po' piú di contesto nel post della domanda.

Comment: Grazie. Letto il secondo brano che hai aggiunto (in specie, dove le competenze di Alfredo sone accostate a quelle di un veterinario) mi sovviene che i maiali maschi vanno (quasi tutti) castrati. _L'accomodatore di porci_...

Comment: Chiesto su news://it.hobby.cucina ① in un racconto di Silone c'è il _sanaporcelli_ che, a memoria di chi mi ha risposto, asporta le ovaie alle scrofe (why?)② un langarolo doc ha scritto _Secondo me intendeva il mediatore di porci, che spesso era anche il "masa crin", che ovviamente conosceva vita morte e miracoli delle stalle di tutti_ e poi  _In Langa e zone limitrofe c'è sempre stato il "masa crin", [...] che ammazzava i maiali, arte difficile, perchè usavano il coltello lungo e con un unico colpo recidevano la colonna vertebrale e l'animale rimaneva
paralizzato e subito dopo lo sgozzavano_

Comment: Ulteriori news da it.hobby.cucina — ringrazio Giacobino/Jacopino da Tradate per il link — [il sanaporcelle](http://www.prodel.it/rabatana/?p=5762051) che riporta anche un brano da Carlo Levi.  Non espando i commenti in una risposta perché le eventuali evidenze sono soltanto indiziarie.

Comment: Credo che il termine usato da Fenoglio sia la traduzione italiana più prossima all'espressione piemontese _ciadela crin_, che si riferisce a colui che si incarica di ammazzare e macellare il maiale

Comment: @Lucius: Questo ha perfettamente senso. Vorreste scriverlo come risposta?

Answer (score 1):

In questo brano "accomodatore di porci" è un dispegiativo per indicare la figura del veterinario dilettante, senza nessuna preparazione specifica ad esercitare il mestiere.
Accomodatore è da intendere come colui che ripara o rimette in sesto in una qualche maniera anche impropria, ma ripristina l'originale utilizzo dell'oggetto. Questo termine accostato a "porci" vuole indicare, appunto, una persona che in qualche modo riesce a rimettere in piedi gli animali (estensione di "porci") con metodi anche non deducibili dalla scienza veterinaria.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Answer (score 0):

Accomodatore può significare chi ripara, quindi accomoda, qualche cosa oppure mette a posto una situazione.

In questo caso però il significato di accomodatore di porci mi sembra semplicemente quello di guardiano di maiali.